# Running jquery on desktop HTML doc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking to make a very basic html doc that shows an image (or multiple images) and when I click on the image, it hides the image.  I can achieve this using jquery.  It works in jsfiddle but for some reason will not work when I just click on the html doc on my desktop and launch it in the browser that way.  What am I missing?  Here is the exact code as I have it in my html doc:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<img id="book" src="C:\Users\user123\Desktop\homeButton.png" alt="" width="100" height="123">

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#book" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $( this ).hide();
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is a link to the working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pLXGu/

When I launch the html doc on my desktop, it takes a long time to load the image (15-20 sec) and when I click the image nothing happens (supposed to hide the image on click).

Comment: Local documents have no protocol, so you need to supply one for jQuery: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that!  It takes a long time to load the image (15-20 sec) and when you click it nothing happens.  (updated OP with that info).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Local documents have no protocol, so you need to supply one for jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>‌​
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I'll accept the answer in 5 minutes (some kind of timer on that function).  I also had to change the file path to the image but that is a different issue entirely.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

try

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you start a URL with `//`, browser will try to retrieve the resource using the protocol that is currently being used. So if your URL was `//ajax.googleapis.com/...`,

- when the main document is online (aka document retrieved using HTTP protocol), it will become `http://ajax.googleapis.com/...`
- But in the desktop, you are using the `file://` protocol. So it becomes `file://ajax.googleapis.com/...`. And that does not refer to any filesystem location.

To remedy this, have your link use the full URL *including* the protocol name.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/...">
```

Answer (score 1):

JQuery librery URL must be give it as

`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js` 
instead of

`//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js`